# Setting max execution time causes Laravel to die

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-ini

I am in the midst of deploying a Laravel application I have written.

The app uses Office365 to send emails over SMTP - unfortunately Office365 is awfully slow.

On my local machine I bumped my max execution time up to 60 seconds and this resolved the issue.

The problem I am having now, is that I cannot globally edit the `php.ini` file in production as the company uses shared hosting.

The host offers the ability to set a `php.ini` file for the directories so you can edit some of these variables.

As such, I have placed a `php.ini` file in the public directory of my app with the below contents:

```
max_execution_time=60
```

However after doing this, trying to access my app results in the below error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 6 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /home/grainfat/capture_html/Capture/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php
>   on line 315 and defined in
>   /home/grainfat/capture_html/Capture/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php:2014
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/grainfat/capture_html/Capture/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php(315):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createRequestFromFactory(Array,
>   Array, Array, Array, Array, NULL) #1
>   /home/grainfat/capture_html/Capture/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php(62):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals() #2
>   /home/grainfat/capture_html/Capture/public/index.php(55):
>   Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() #3 {main} thrown in
>   /home/grainfat/capture_html/Capture/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php
>   on line 2014

As soon as I remove the `php.ini` file it goes away.

Any ideas as to why this causes the above error? Or suggestions for an alternative workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your necessary php settings in your `.htaccess` file.
Ex:

> php_value max_execution_time 60

Answer (score 0):

Along with `max_execution_time`, Also add `memory_limit` at top of your `.htaccess` file

> php_value memory_limit 256M
>
> php_value max_execution_time 60